# How to trigger a new build of a GitLab project

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to follow the tutorial https://about.gitlab.com/2016/03/01/gitlab-runner-with-docker/, and I've got to the part where

```
Runner registered successfully. Feel free to start it, but if it's running already the config should be automatically reloaded!
```

In the **CI/CD Pipelines** sections of the **Settings** for the project (which I created as a **New Project** specifying the https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/nodejs/ URL to clone from), I see the following:

[image]

In the tutorial it is then stated, without further explanation,

> Finally, we are ready to trigger a new build. We should see the next build running with our specific runner on our private server.

How am I supposed to "trigger a new build"? Is it by doing a `git push` in my local version of the repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [GitLab CI documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/quick_start/README.html#getting-started-with-gitlab-ci) (emphasis mine):

> If you add a .gitlab-ci.yml file to the root directory of your repository, and configure your GitLab project to use a Runner, then **each merge request or push, triggers your CI pipeline**.

So yes, each push will trigger a new build, but also merge requests (handled trough the webinterface) will trigger a new build.

Comment: In addition, I had to use `sudo` when registering the Runner. (The exclamation mark in the **Settings** page is because the Runner was not connected, which turned into a green circle when I re-registered using `sudo`).

Answer (score 3):

To expand on @Fairy's answer. Gitlab build can be triggered by:

- a push
- a call to a [trigger](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/triggers/README.html#trigger-a-job)
- a [webhook](https://gitlab.scm.webanywhere.co.uk/help/web_hooks/web_hooks), that is triggered by actions happening on different projects
- Manually by going to the `Pipelines` tab and clicking `Run pipeline`